# set data in string at specific location using SQL

Tags: sql

Using data from a SQL db, I need to fill a string with 60 pieces of data set at specific locations. For example, data 1 will be at myString location 1 to 4, data 2 will be at 5 to 10, etc.

```
mySQL SELECT INSERT('Originalstring', 4, 5, ' insert ')
```

would be perfect but I am using SQL. How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Perhaps you just want `concat()`.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing are you wanting to just combine several sets of strings into one long string? or are you wanting to insert your custom string into a pre-existing string at set intervals?

Comment: Yes checked into concat(). The issue is my data may not fill the whole location size. Example: if data 1 is supposed to be in position 1 to 4 but is only length of 2, data 2 must still start at position 5.

Comment: Sorry. combine data retrieved from db (int, strings, datetime, etc) into one long string at set intervals. I will have to convert int into string but yes in the end, combined into one long string at set intervals.

Comment: See my answer for (what seems to be, anyway) the `tsql` equivalent of mysql's `SELECT INSERT`. Although, if possible, I'd recommend doing this in the code instead of in the database. String manipulation is clunky and weird in `sql` and you'd be much better served having the application logic take care of this and pass the updated value down.

Comment: True on application logic suggestion. I will test STUFF to see if I can get it to work for me. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).

```
declare @originalString varchar(50) = 'This is my string',
        @stringToStuff varchar(10) = 'new '

SELECT  STUFF(@originalString, 12, 0, @stringToStuff)
```

This will insert the string `@stringToStuff` at index 12 of `@originalString` (immediately following the space after my).

Comment: This is awesome I did not know Stuff was a thing in SQL. This could be useful.